# Swift NSDateFormatter using a quotation mark

Tags: swift, nsformatter

This code works:

```
        let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "MMM d yy"
        return fmt.stringFromDate(mydate)
```

Returns `Dec 31 10`

But if I try to get this `Dec 31 '10` using

```
        fmt.dateFormat = "MMM d 'yy"
```

It doesn't work, get `Dec 31 yy`

How can you include the quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
fmt.dateFormat = "MMM d ''yy"
```